# How to wait until ssh is available?

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to code a script which will wait for a server to be up and check if ssh is running.

```
#!/bin/bash

until [ $(ssh -o BatchMode=yes -o ConnectTimeout=5 root@HOST echo ok 2>&1) = "ok" ]; do
    echo "Trying again..."
done

echo "SSH is running"
```

I have this error if server is power off :

```
test3: ligne 3 : [: Too many arguments
Trying again...
^C
```

If server is running it output :
`ok`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trivial fix is to put double quotes around the string which might come up empty.

```
until [ "$(ssh ...)" = "ok" ]; do ...
```

The Bash-only test `[[` is more tolerant, so you could use `[[` ... `]]` instead of `[` ... `]` and not have to add quotes.

... but a better solution is to look for the exit status from `ssh`:

```
until ssh ...; do ...
```

If you want the operation to be silent, add a redirection.

```
until ssh user@hostname true >/dev/null 2>&1; do ...
```

with whatever additional options you want, of course.  You might need to add one or more `ssh -t` options if it complains about not being connected to a TTY, for example.

Comment: How can I hide the output of login failed ?

Comment: Add `>/dev/null 2>&1` or some such. This is an extremely common FAQ.

Comment: And How can I avoid connecting to the server ? Only checking if server ssh is running

Comment: You are connecting by definition if you are using `ssh` and looking for it to succeed. Something like `ssh hostname true` will immediately disconnect with a successful return status.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ssh` command is expanding to nothing, or to multiple words; you should quote it (and run Shellcheck on your script):

```
until [ "$(ssh ... )" = ok ]; do
```